# On the iPhone, is it possible to find out which WIFI network we are connected to?

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, detect, ssid

If yes, can we also get additional information about the network configuration?

One useful way to do this could be getting the SSID of the current network. Is there an API to do that?

Update: I found a similar question here:

[Can the iPhone SDK obtain the Wi-Fi SSID currently connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625158/iphone-sdk-detect-wifi-and-carrier-network

Comment: No, not a duplicate of that. This questioner wants to know *which* WiFi network he's connected to, not *whether* he's connected to one, or whether he's connected via mobile only (or not at all).

Comment: Until a few weeks ago there were an application called WifiTrak (http://www.bitrino.com/wifitrak/support.html) on the appstore which displayed a list of all available wi-fi hotspots in range.
It has however been pulled from the appstore, so even though it appeared that this is possible it might not be acceptable by Apple for whatever reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Separate answer to preserve history etc.)

It looks like you might not be able to determine the SSID of the WLAN to which you're connected, at least in an app that will go into the App Store. [These people](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) use a private API - Preferences.framework - to get to the details of the WLAN (like "is it hidden?" "What's the name?" etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Try following method:

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

NSString *wifiName = @"Not Found";
CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();

if (myArray != nil) {

    CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));

    if (myDict != nil) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(myDict);

        wifiName = [dict valueForKey:@"SSID"];

    }  
}

NSLog(@"wifiName:%@", wifiName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, but this might be a duplicate:

[Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)

Answer seems to be no. I've done my own research on this and have been unable to find a supported way of getting the SSID.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app?

Edit: The Reachability app demonstrates the use of the SystemConfiguration framework to show whether your phone's connected to the internet and, if so, how.

It further allows you to distinguish between a local WiFi connection and not (+[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi]).

Regarding the meat of your question, you'll have to consult the phone's ARP table. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/howto-query-arp-table-on-iphone/2269903#2269903) shows you how to do just that.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your answer. Are you saying "yes, you can, here's a link to some sample code that does it" or are you saying "no, you can't; but here's an idea of the other things you can do." Or are you saying "I don't know either, but look over here" which really would be better as a comment, as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The reachability sample only demonstrates detecting IF we are connected to a network. It does not show how we can get the current network's identification.

Comment: What do you mean by a network's identification? Do you mean the SSID of a WLAN?

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure what I wanted when I asked the question. But on some thought, yes, the SSID.