# Need some help with Reachability (2.0.3ddg)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reachability

When my app launches, I check for reachability because I need an immediate internet connection. My problem, though, is that it appears there's no immediate confirmation for the `NetworkStatus`, which means right after the Reachability is setup, I check whether there's a connection, and it returns that there isn't, regardless of whether I am in fact on WiFi/3G, or have turned the radio off.

I can confirm that I am in fact getting an Internet connection, because instantly after applicationDidFinishLaunching, there's a notification which then logs "ReachableViaWiFi"..

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not confirming a valid Internet connection right away?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
        ErrorViewController *errorViewController = [[ErrorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ErrorView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [window addSubview:[errorViewController view]];
        return;
    }
}

-(void)setupReachability {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
    hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"] retain];
    [hostReach startNotifier];
}

-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability* curReach = [notification object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL connectionRequired = [curReach connectionRequired];
    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:kNOTREACHABLE forKey:kREACHABILITYSTATUS];
            NSLog(@"NotReachable");
            connectionRequired = NO;  
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:kREACHABLEVIAWWAN forKey:kREACHABILITYSTATUS];
            NSLog(@"ReachableViaWWAN");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:kNOTREACHABLE forKey:kREACHABILITYSTATUS];
            NSLog(@"ReachableViaWiFi");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so after trying a few things out myself, I actually got it to work, by adding one extra line of code:

```
-(void)setupReachability {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotificationV2 object:nil];
    hostReach = [[ReachabilityV2 reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"] retain];
    [hostReach connectionRequired]; // this line was added, and apparently forces a connection requirement..
    [hostReach startNotifier];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Reachability sample code provides you with asynchronous callbacks/notifications to inform you of how/when the reachability has changed. In order for your code to work, you should modify your code as follows:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

 // setup reachability
    [self setupReachability];
 }
```

Then in your callback, when you get the notification you react as needed by your application.

In other words, you can not check immediately for the network status in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`. If you want to do so, then you must use a synchronous/blocking method, for instance you can use the code provided in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448411/how-to-check-for-local-wi-fi-not-just-cellular-connection-using-iphone-sdk) question.

Comment: I can add confirmation that Apple has said reachability is not a pre-flight check.  If you want to have it work as soon as possible, try opening up some confirmation URL right on app launch which should have Reachability fire off a notification as to connection status.

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to set something like "isConnectionRequired", which forces a network check?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make hostReach as class level variable.